# how to access angularjs scope variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, javascript-objects

i am trying to get $scope variable value in my js code where i have defines instance gs and it object is language, i want to change my object value 'fr' to my `$scope.lang.languagesel` value.

```
$scope.change=function() {
    if($scope.data.defaultLanguage=="de_DE") {
        $scope.lang.languagesel = 'nl'
    } else if($scope.data.defaultLanguage=="fr_FR") { 
        $scope.lang.languagesel = 'fr'
    } else {
        $scope.lang.languagesel = 'nl'
    }
}
$scope.lang={};
$scope.lang.languagesel = 'nl';
```

and my js code like

```
var g = new gs("map", { language:'fr' });
```

how can i get the value of scope variable 'en' in language object

Comment: Where is language object ?

Comment: Where are you instantiating `gs` ? inside controller ?

Comment: post the controller code or directive code if any !

Comment: it is outside of the controller and not using any directive.

Comment: how can i define same line in agularjs var g = new gs("map", { language:'fr' });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the variable to window and then access it in normal javascript:

```
$window.lang = $scope.lang.languagesel;
```

And later in Javascript:

```
var g = new gs("map", { language:window.lang });
```